# Unit of Work pattern and persistence

Tags: unit-of-work, unitofworkapplication

I have been reading about Unit of Work pattern but I am confused about how the UoW actually persists data.

When we commit the changes, UoW should iterate through the list of Added, Updated and Deleted objects and somehow find a class responsible to Add, Update, Delete objects of a certain type.

I couldn't find an example showing this technique.

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Mosh

Comment: what language / framework?  theres lots and lots on the net!